# Rails3: cannot load such file -- sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I've decided to make my old resume site responsive by including seyhunak's gem twitter-bootstrap-rails in my assets group and updating the app to 3.2.14. I yanked out my Blueprint files and updating my css as needed. I was going OK when I decided to edit one of my .scss files and blam! I got the above error when the app attempted to load my application.css file.

Reading up on the subject and SO I've verified that my application css should see my tree along with bootstrap. I've also added back in the gems to use SASS as well as the bootstrap LESS files. It's almost like the server is loading up the precompiled css and it crashes when it changes. But making a change after stopping the server yields the same error on reload.

Here's my application.css

```
  *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
  *= require_self
  *= require_tree .
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'
 gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
 gem "friendly_id", "~> 4.0.0"
 gem 'pg'
 group :assets do
   gem 'less-rails'
   gem 'coffee-rails'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
   gem "therubyracer"
   gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
 end
 gem 'ruby-rc4', :require => "rc4"
 gem 'nokogiri'
 gem 'multi_json'
 gem 'jquery-rails'

 group :test do
   gem 'cucumber-rails'
   gem 'database_cleaner'
   gem 'spork', "~> 0.9.0.rc"
   gem "factory_girl"
   gem "launchy"
   gem "pry"
   gem "rspec-rails"
 end

 gem "passenger", "~> 3.0.11"
 gem "capistrano", "~> 2.9.0"
 gem 'contact_us', '~> 0.4.0.beta'
 gem 'prawn'
```

Here's my development.rb:

```
   config.cache_classes = false
   config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
   config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
   config.active_support.deprecation = :log
   config.assets.compress = false
   config.assets.debug = true
```

The bootstrap_and_overrides file, as well as the welcome.css.scss file are in app/stylesheets/ directory. The log just spits out the 500 page for template error with the title message. The file is the welcome.css.scss page. Thx.

It's probably simple which is why my Google search is fruitless, but I'm not seeing it, thanx, sam

Comment: Have you got bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less in your assets/stylesheets folder? Also, just to be clear - the scss file you were editing is also in assets/stylesheets?

Comment: What's in the log files?

Comment: show your whole gemfile.